# Why is Firebase email verification giving me a http 400 error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to add email verification in my React website but nothing seems to be working. When I initiate the `sendSignInLinkToEmail` function, it returns this error:

```
XHRPOSThttps://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[HTTP/3 400 Bad Request 455ms]
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_CONTINUE_URI : Missing domain in continue url",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_CONTINUE_URI : Missing domain in continue url",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Code in question:

```
export const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
  try {
    await sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(() => {
        // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
        // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
        // if they open the link on the same device.
        window.localStorage.setItem("emailForSignIn", email);
        console.log("test");
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
      });
      
    const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    const user = res.user;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      uid: user.uid,
      name,
      authProvider: "local",
      email,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert(err.message);
  }
};
```

actionCodeSettings:

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
  url: "/",
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: "com.example.ios",
  },
  android: {
    packageName: "com.example.android",
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: "12",
  },
  //dynamicLinkDomain: "example.page.link",
};
```

The problem probably lies in the actionCodeSettings, I want my website to redirect to root after performing the registration. By the way, I am locally hosting this website, it is not public.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error [means](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors):

> The continue URL must be a valid URL string.

So... you got that right, `/` is a valid URL string. But the response "Missing domain in continue url" suggests that it must be an *absolute* URL. So this is not valid:

```
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
  url: "/",
```

Put the full URL of your website there, including `http://` or `https://` and the domain name. And, as the comment mentions, make sure it's authorized in the Firebase Console.

Comment: Ok, but now it gives me "DYNAMIC_LINK_NOT_ACTIVATED : FDL domain is not configured"

Comment: Different error, different question.

Comment: It isn't letting me post another question because the min delay is 90mins, do you at least know the answer?

Comment: I don't, sorry. Have you tried configuring a dynamic link domain at all? Whatever that means -- I'm out of my depth here.